# como igualar variable al último campo de una base de datos c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

me gustaría extraer el último campo insertado en una base de datos e igualarlo a una variable para poder trabajar con el dato, he escrito esto pero siempre que he trabajado con datasets los he utilizado para rellenar tablas o trabajar con todos los campos de la tabla, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo extaigo el dato de esta consulta y lo igualo a una variable? Gracias.

```
            CN.Open();

            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT ULTIMAMEDIDA FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID = MAX(ID)) ", CN);

            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int ultimaMedida = ?¿?¿ // aquí desearía asignar el valor de mi consulta

            CN.Close();
```

Comment: utiliza sqldatareader read; y en un if puedes hacer if(read.Read()) int ultimamedida = Convert.toInt32(read[0].toString());

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar Sqldatareader de la siguiente manera:

```
 CN.Open();

        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT ULTIMAMEDIDA FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID = MAX(ID)) ", CN);
        SqlDataReader read;
        read = CMD.ExecuteReader();
if(read.Read())
         {
        int ultimaMedida = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
}
        CN.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con :

```
int ultimaMedida = CMD.ExecuteScalar ();
```

Cuidado si puede devolver null por lo que sea.

Answer (score 2):

Esa consulta en Sql Server no es funcional. Puedes probar

```
 using (SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(CSTR))
 {
     int ultimaMedida;
     using (SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ULTIMAMEDIDA),0) FROM REGISTRO;", CN))
     {
          CN.Open();
          ultimaMedida = (int)CMD.ExecuteScalar();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Pero esa consulta que devuelve exactamente?? Necesito extraer el último dato insertado en la tabla

Comment: Devuelve el útlimo valor de ULTIMAMEDIDA. Si no existe ninguno, devuelve un 0. Así te aseguras, de que al llegar a c# y realizar el cast a int, del valor que resuelve la consulta, siempre tiene un valor y no genera una excepción.

Comment: Ojo si el campo es ID y no ULTIMAMEDIDA, solo tienes que cambiar uno por otro